# what is the default value for write timeout in postgres and MSSQL database connections?

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql

I am using different databases to run my application. Recently I increased net_write_timeout value in mysql database, As I faced some timeout errors due to that. These errors are not occurred in Postgres or Mssql database.

My question is what is the equivalent flag of net_write_timeout (Mysql) for Postgres and Mssql database.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server there are a couple of timeouts but nothing that directly corresponds to the net_write_timeout - afaik...

The default connection timeout (time allowed to connect to an instance) is 15 seconds. The default execution timeout (time allowed to execute a query etc) is 600. Connection timeout is set on the connection string, execution timeout on the connection in code, or at the server level by `sp_configure`

Refs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189040.aspx
and http://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about postgres database?

Comment: @AravindharajG I don't think there is something similar in postgresql.